# Firebase Auth Emulator failing to sign JWT when using Dgraph Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, dgraph

I am trying to find a good way to use the Firebase auth emulator and Dgraph. In Dgraph you send a JWT which contains claims that you can check in Dgraph to allow / limit queries and mutations.

In the Dgraph schema you are required to add the below code:

```
# Dgraph.Authorization {"Header":"X-Auth-Token","Namespace":"https://dgraph.io/jwt/claims","JWKURL":"https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com","Audience":["firebase-project-id"]}
```

I am finding the `JWKURL` value is invalid when using the firebase auth emulator. It returns this error.

```
couldn't rewrite query getUser because unable to parse jwt token:token is unverifiable: Keyfunc returned an error
```

When I try try to use the `localhost` url Dgraph fails as it can't connect to it.

For example:

```
localhost:9099/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Hello, I'm having issues getting DGraph to recognize the token claims. Were you able to get it to work (not in the emulator)?